# apollo graph manager 406: Not Acceptable

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to use apollo graph manager, but keep getting this error, when i try to publish my graph to apollo graph manager from my local terminal.

```
apollo service:push --endpoint=http://localhost:3050/graphql --key="service:salading_test"
  ✔ Loading Apollo Project
  ✔ Loading Apollo Project
  ✖ Uploading service to Apollo Graph Manager
    → 406: Not Acceptable
Error: 406: Not Acceptable
```

This is what I got from apollo graph manager

```
ENGINE_API_KEY=service:salading_test:<key>
```

I copied it and added it to my .env file and restarted my server.
In my server.js, I also tried with the following settings:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const apolloInstance = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    playground: true,
    introspection: true,
    engine: { //added
      apiKey: process.env.ENGINE_API_KEY
    }
  });

apolloInstance.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false }); 
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

Now the tutorial in apollo docs uses `'apollo-server'` instead of `'apollo-server-express'`. But that shouldnt be a problem, since `'apollo-server'` is used inside `'apollo-server-express'`?

Answer (score 2):

this error would indicate that you do not have the correct ENGINE_API_KEY loaded: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/1166

Comment: Yeah -- this was the issue for me. What happened to meaningful error messages...?

Comment: or just use the correct HTTP response in the first place